# Is it possible to create analytic report from multiple class on openerp 7?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

Is it possible to create analytic report from multiple class ? for example I want to create summary report sales order, budgeting, invoicing in one page. I am so glad if I can create custom chart or custom query too.

Comment: This question is far too broad for SO so I'm flagging to close. SO is designed for specific programming questions in Q&A format. This sort of question is better suited to a forum or subreddit.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit broad, but i understand where it's leading: Business Intelligence.

Yes it could be possible to combine data from multiple business models. Actually Odoo is doing excatly that in their reports like the invoice reports.

It's done by creating new Odoo models which do not create their own tables but database views. [Here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/a19d2c98f4c80d162a92d08ce4a43ca6021f3bca/addons/account/report/account_invoice_report.py) is an example (invoice report) from Odoo 11.

Database views always have their advantages and disadvantages, but that shouldn't be the topic here.

Now you have to get your requirements together and to create your own BI Odoo model. Of course, not everything is possible and can fail due to topics such as missing relations or performance.